# Data structure with logarithmic insert/delete and "no-greater-than"

Tags: java, data-structures, tail, head

I'm solving a coding challenge right now, and I have a solution, but for it to work, I need a data structure which supports four operations:

- Insertion in O(log(N))
- Deletion in O(log(N))
- Checking how many elements are greater than a specified element in O(log(N))
- Checking how many elements are less than a specified element in O(log(N))

I tried solving it using Java's `TreeSet` which can support these operations by `add`, `remove`, `headSet` and `tailSet` (and checking the size of the two last ones). But this solution is too slow. I haven't checked the time complexities but I have a feeling that `...set` do not run in logarithmic time (or run inefficiently).

Does anyone know of a data structure I can implement to support these operations? Is it even possible? And, if it is in some tree shape, preferably self-balancing?

Comment: Have a look at [Order statistic trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree) I don't know about java implementations though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, "Order statistic trees" solved the problem I asked for elegantly, and in addition, were relatively easy to implement, and ultimately gave me an accepted submission for the challenge. Thanks!